# Spring4 mvc + Tiles3: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-tiles, spring-4

i'm having trouble using Spring 4 MVC and Tiles 3. Here is my dispatcher XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="it.giuliosoro.controller" /> 

 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <!-- Tiles configuration -->
 <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000"/>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

while my web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app id="WebApp_ID"
    version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring 4 Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

And my tiles definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="defaultTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/template/default/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Dependencies seems to be loaded correctly by the pom:

```
<!-- Apache Tiles -->   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
    <version>${tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
    <version>${tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>${tiles.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <tiles.version>3.0.4</tiles.version>
</properties>
```

And finally this is spring complaining:

```
08:29:30,390 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:530 - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#6bc0cd80': [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0]
08:29:30,391 ERROR ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/IllformedLocaleException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/IllformedLocaleException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext.getResources(SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.getSources(TilesConfigurer.java:305)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createLocaleDefinitionDao(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:182)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(TilesConfigurer.java:350)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(TilesConfigurer.java:296)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:114)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(TilesConfigurer.java:270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.IllformedLocaleException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 34 more
24-mag-2014 8.29.30 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

I've no more ideas, it seems a recurrent problem also with spring3, but i already tried several of the solution proposed on StackOverflow involving tilesresolver vs urlbasedview resolver or  adding dependencies (common-digester, common-beanutils or tiles-extra) but nothing seems to disturb the noclassdef!

Thank you!

Comment: Which java version do you use? java.util.IllformedLocaleException is available since java 7

Comment: @Jens, thank you.. turned out i was completely looking at the wrong place! eclipse was using default JRE 1.6, instead of JDK 7.. great!

Comment: @Jens I would suggest adding your response as an answer so that jojo could properly accept it and you can get your points.

Comment: @CodeChimp I have done it. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which java version do you use? `java.util.IllformedLocaleException` is available since java 7

Answer (score 6):

Tiles-3 is intended to support Java6.
The Tiles-3.0.4 release broke that.

Either use Java7 or downgrade to Tiles-3.0.3.

Also expect a release of Tiles-3.0.5
Note to others: "-source 1.6 won't fail on uses of IllformedLocaleException".

Comment: and should 3.0.5 support Java 6 again ?